# requires android.permission.INTERNET when using phone to debug

Tags: android

For some reason, the emulator works fine for the app. However, when I deploy the app directly to the phone I get an error message.

```
 [2011-07-19 22:30:27 - DOL Agency Names] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException:

Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 

cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 

cmp=my.smh.dolagencynames/.DOLAgencyNamesActivity } 
from null (pid=2344, uid=2000) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

And, the app shows as installed on the phone but when I click on the app it says the application was not installed.

I have even signed the app and installed it from the sd card.
I even tried to install it with adb install.

For some reason, this app will not install on my phone.
The phone version is 2.2.
I have built the app for both 1.5 and 2.2. Neither works.

Comment: That's strange, so you have the permission in the manifest, or it works on the emulator without the permission?

Comment: You have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in you manifest, right (somewhere inside the `<manifest>` tag)?

Comment: can you please update your code?

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest if you app is making any network requests (this includes calls that might make network requests for you, like analytics).

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) explains permissions. You'll want to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Make sure you're using `uses-permission` and not `permission`. They do different things.